# using mget within a function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write a simple function in in `r` that will search the `.GlobalEnv` for objects with a specific pattern in their names, then take that list and bind the elements into a data frame.

When run separately, this works as expected:

```
# create sample data

df1_pattern_to_find <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2)
df2_pattern_to_find <- data.frame(a = 3, b = 4)

# use mget to generate a list of objects

list_of_objects <- mget(ls(pattern="_pattern_to_find"))

# bind the elements together into a data frame

do.call("rbind", list_of_objects)

                    a b
df1_pattern_to_find 1 2
df2_pattern_to_find 3 4
```

However, when I wrap the above in a function it returns `NULL`:

```
gather_function <- function() {
  list_of_objects <- mget(ls(pattern="_pattern_to_find"))

  df <- do.call("rbind", list_of_objects)

  df
}

gather_function()

NULL
```

I have tried explicitly setting `envir` within `mget` to `.GlobalEnv` and that doesn't seem to be the issue.

I know I am missing something simple here.

Comment: You need to set `envir` within `ls` too

Comment: The real question is why are those individual dataframes not in a list in the first place? Check the source of that code and avoid needing `mget` or `eapply`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you're calling `ls` and `mget` within a function, the environment is no longer the same as when called from the top-level environment.

You can hard-code the environment to search the top-level as follows:

```
list_of_objects <- mget(ls(.GlobalEnv, pattern = "_pattern_to_find"), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Your problem was `ls` wasn't returning any objects in the first place so setting the `envir` parameter within `mget` alone won't help.

---

An alternative which avoids hard-coding `.GlobalEnv` is to search all enclosing parent frames:

```
mget(apropos("_pattern_to_find"), inherits = TRUE)
```

This will match the pattern `"_pattern_to_find"` and return any objects in enclosing environments.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. Thanks for clarifying the environment nesting here.